# Sqlite data storage from server

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I am building an android app in cross platform, in my app when i store data in sqlite from remote server it gets stored in a single column of the table, not storing in particular columns. i am getting data in JSON object and also i tried to JSON.strinify..but still.whole data stores in a single column.

Here is my Code

```
$("#xxx").click(function()
{

    var e = $("#mob").val();
    var p = $("#key").val();
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction)
    {
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User_data (data)', [],
            function(tx, result)
            {
                navigator.notification.alert("table created");
            }, 
            function(error)
            {
                navigator.notification.alert("error, table exists");
            });
    });

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://192.168.1.4/sms/android.php",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { type:'login', phone: e, name: p },
        ContentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response)
        {

            myDB.transaction(function(transaction)
            {
                var valuesInArray = JSON.stringify(response);



                transaction.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO User_data (data) VALUES (?)", valuesInArray,
                function(tx, result) 
                {
                    navigator.notification.alert("registerd");
                }, 
                function(error)
                {
                    navigator.notification.alert("error, table exists");
                });
            }); 
        },
        error: function(e)
        {

            alert('Got ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You have to extract the JSON and save every value in it's column. if you don't have the column in your sqlite table, then you have to alter the table. If JSON data is the standard in your app, I would think about PouchDB, it is a NoSQL database.

Comment: but how to extract JSON to insert it in every column, since when i do it by above code it data gets store in a single column